# Laravel 6 - Route post not found

Tags: php, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to implement `Register User` in NuxtJS. However, I'm having this issue like below

> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php

**`In My api Route`**

```
 Route::post('register', 'V1\Auth\LoginController@register');
```

I'm try change it to `get method` and access it by `127.0.0.1:8000/api/register` its work pretty fine.

i still have no idea, why i got this `POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/register 404 (Not Found)`

**`In My Nuxtjs`**

```
           async registerUser() {
                try {
                    await this.$axios.post(`api/register`, this.auth);
                    await this.$auth.login({
                        data: {
                            email: this.auth.email,
                            password: this.auth.password,
                        }
                    })
                    .then(res => {
                        console.log(res);
                        this.loading = false
                        // this.$router.push(`/auth/login`);
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        this.loading = false
                        this.$refs.form.validate(err.response.data.errors)
                        console.log(err.response);
                    })
                } catch(e) {
                    // statements
                    console.log(e);
                }
```

**`In My Controller`**

```
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|between:6, 25',
        ]);

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->save();

        return response()->json(['registered' => true ]);
    }
```

I'll appreciate of all your Help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 3000 port `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/register` in the axios, but the laravel use 8000 `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register`

Answer (score 0):

You have to establish the API base URL In NuxtJS APP.

The reason is that Your NuxtJS app set default it's own base URL 
But you have to configure backend URL for laravel API.

Example,

Try This

```
await this.$axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register`, this.auth);
```